# Proof of an alternative min-max inequality

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

The standard [max-min inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max%E2%80%93min_inequality) states that, for a bivariate function $f: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$,

$$
\sup_x \inf_y f(x,y) \le \inf_y \sup_x f(x,y). \qquad (*)
$$

I wonder whether the following property is also a max-min inequality:

$$
\sup_x \inf_y f(x,y) \le \inf_x \sup_y f(x,y), \qquad (**)
$$

since
$$
\begin{align}
\inf_{y_0} f(x,y_0) &\le f(x,y) &\quad \forall x\forall y\\
\sup_{x_0} \inf_{y_0} f(x_0,y_0) &\le \sup_{x_0} f(x_0,y) &\quad \forall y\\
\sup_{x_0} \inf_{y_0} f(x_0,y_0) &\le \inf_{y_0}\sup_{x_0} f(x_0,y_0).
\end{align}
$$

I am wondering whether (a) the proposed min-max inequality (**) is indeed correct based on the proof, and if so, (b) why it is not as widely used or referenced in minimax theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof you gave seems to conclude with (*) rather than (**).

(**) is false, as you can see for instance with $f(x,y)=x$.